# parent click does not work on child link though link is dissabled

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with handling clcik event. I have a div and a link inside it. I want to disable the link and instead where ever the div is clicked a function should be executed. So inorder to disable the link I return false whenever link is clicked but what I want at the same time is when the link is clicked still the parent div gets executed. Here is my code and fiddle link:

```
$(".div").click(function(){
   alert("Hello");

});

$("a").click(function(e){
   return false;

});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5n1kpcsp/1/)

As you can see if I click anywhere in the div it works except in the area when link exists.

Can anyone help me?

*******************UPDATE***********************************

So no matter where is clciked, every click anywhere on div should execute alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not `return false` in your event's callback function, it is causing to prevent bubbling. That's the reason of not triggering click event on parent.

To prevent redirecting on `a` click you should prevent default behavior, like this:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Check the snippet:

```js
$(".div").click(function(){
   alert("Hello");
});

$("a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.div {
  width: 300px; 
  height: 300px; 
  display: block; 
  background: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div">
  <a href="http://google.com">link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes

change this:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
  return false;
});
```

to this:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
  $(".div").click();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not return false just [preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) for the link ( If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered. )

`return false` from within a jQuery event handler is effectively the same as calling both e.preventDefault and e.stopPropagation on the passed 
[jQuery.Event](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/)
 object.

```
$(".div").click(function(){
alert("Hello");
});

$("a").click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `pointer-events: none;` css attribute, without `$("a").click()` event.

```
a.disabled{
  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/5n1kpcsp/4/